# How to migrate Tensorflow 1.x class to Tensorflow 2.1.x

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

For my learning project, since im new in RNN stuff, i have class in python which i think uses Tensorflow 1.x and seems a few things has been deprecated, the actual goal is to change the LSTM to CuDNNLSTM, but first i need to migrate to Tensorflow 2.1.x

```py
class Model:
    def __init__(
        self,
        learning_rate,
        num_layers,
        size,
        size_layer,
        output_size,
        forget_bias = 0.1,
    ):
        def lstm_cell(size_layer):
            return tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size_layer, state_is_tuple = False)

        rnn_cells = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
            [lstm_cell(size_layer) for _ in range(num_layers)],
            state_is_tuple = False,
        )
        self.X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, size))
        self.Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, output_size))
        drop = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(
            rnn_cells, output_keep_prob = forget_bias
        )
        self.hidden_layer = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(
            tf.float32, (None, num_layers * 2 * size_layer)
        )
        self.outputs, self.last_state = tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            drop, self.X, initial_state = self.hidden_layer, dtype = tf.float32
        )
        self.logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(self.outputs[-1], output_size)
        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.Y - self.logits))
        self.optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(
            self.cost
        )
```

I been trying to to change few things like: changing `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` to `tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell` and `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell` to `tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells` also `tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn` to `tf.keras.layers.RNN`

To something like:

```py
class Model:
    def __init__(
        self,
        learning_rate,
        num_layers,
        size,
        size_layer,
        output_size,
        forget_bias = 0.1,
    ):
        def lstm_cell(size_layer):
            return tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(size_layer)

        rnn_cells = tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells(
            [lstm_cell(size_layer) for _ in range(num_layers)]
        )
        self.X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, size))
        self.Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, output_size))
        drop = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(
            rnn_cells, output_keep_prob = forget_bias
        )
        self.hidden_layer = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(
            tf.float32, (None, num_layers * 2 * size_layer)
        )

        self.outputs, self.last_state = tf.keras.layers.RNN(
            drop, self.X, initial_state = self.hidden_layer, dtype = tf.float32
        )
        self.logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(self.outputs[-1], output_size)
        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.Y - self.logits))
        self.optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(
            self.cost
        )
```

But the result still is not as expected.

Comment: Do you want to update to TF2.0 with the compat.v1 module or do want to change it to keras module ?

Comment: keras module, some deprecated function refers the update to keras module

Comment: You can't use placeholders here. Try with `tf.keras.layers.Input` instead.

Comment: If you could provide the architecture of the model your are trying to make would be easier to convert using just keras.

Comment: what do you mean by architecture? sorry for this

Comment: The direction of your model. Example: Inputs -> LSTM Layer(128 units) -> Dense -> Loss.

Comment: @FebrianKurniawan, The link, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate might help you. Thanks!